# How to add AND to foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox, drawing

I have two listbox(listboxlong and listboxlat) and I have picture box to draw values(by using timer(timer1)) in listboxes. I want to attend listboxes values for each line to picturebox x and y values(listboxlong for x values, listboxlat for y values). Even I tried foreach loop I couldn't achieve it. If there is a code which works as foreach with AND please let me know. Thanks for your help. Here is my code;

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBoxPath.Refresh();
       listBoxLong.Items.Add(gPathBoylam);
       listBoxLat.Items.Add(gPathEnlem);
     }
  private void pictureBoxPath_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

       foreach (var item in listBoxLat.Items)
        {
              foreach (var item2 in listBoxLong.Items)
            {
          e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, Convert.ToInt16(item), Convert.ToInt16(item2), 2, 2);
            }

        }           

    }
```

Comment: So what error are you getting, the "AND" question is not making sense to me, but regardless, what issues are you seeing? I see your trying to cast a listbox item as an int... have not tried that, but I'd imagine you should be after the item.value....

Comment: Please provide a clearer description of your problem.

Comment: A foreach loop is meant to do one thing and one thing only: loop through each element in some collection. It does not and can not check for another condition within the `foreach(..)` part. If you want to loop over 2 collections, you need to nest them, as you have done. Or, use a different loop (such as for).

Comment: Firstly thanks for your replies
@Trey and @MetaColon:
If I can use something as below I think everything wil be okay and this is why 'AND' question should be make sense.
       `foreach (var item in listBoxLat.Items && var item2 in listBoxLong.Items)
{
 e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, Convert.ToInt16(item), Convert.ToInt16(item2), 2, 2);
}`
@DangerZone: I tried for loop but I couldn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize your qustion is not very clear, but reading your comments and looking specially for this:

```
foreach(var item in listBoxLat.Items && var item2 in listBoxLong.Items)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, Convert.ToInt16(item), Convert.ToInt16(item2), 2, 2);
}
```

I think you are trying to run the first item of one list to the first item to the other list and go on. That menas you are synchronizing them.

So a better approach would be using tuples to store in a list of tuples. And you need to realize how "`Graphics.DrawEllipse`" works. So I put the documentation summary below.

So the following code may work, I couldn't test this because I'm at work right now.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> myTuple = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBoxPath.Refresh();

    myTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(gPathBoylam, gPathEnlem));  
}

//
// Summary:
//     Draws an ellipse defined by a bounding rectangle specified by coordinates
//     for the upper-left corner of the rectangle, a height, and a width.
//
// Parameters:
//   pen:
//     System.Drawing.Pen that determines the color, width,
//      and style of the ellipse.
//
//   x:
//     The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the bounding rectangle that
//     defines the ellipse.
//
//   y:
//     The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the bounding rectangle that
//     defines the ellipse.
//
//   width:
//     Width of the bounding rectangle that defines the ellipse.
//
//   height:
//     Height of the bounding rectangle that defines the ellipse.
//
// Exceptions:
//   System.ArgumentNullException:
//     pen is null.
private void pictureBoxPath_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{   
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3); // Create pen

    if(myTuple != null && myTuple.Any())
    {
        foreach (var tuple in myTuple)
        {   
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt16(tuple.Item1), Convert.ToInt16(tuple.Item2), 2, 2); // Create rectangle for ellipse

            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, rect); // Draw ellipse to screen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Andrew it is what exactly what I want.Just there is a tiny mistake in your code suc as;
`foreach (var tuple in myTuple)` should be instead of `foreach (var tuple in myValues)`

Comment: Edited and fixed. ;)